# vscode auto import with already exists code

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-import

Sometimes i have already predefined code and i want functions to autoimport with Quick Fix action is it possible ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is conservative when checking JavaScript code. Variables such as `beforeSaveWarrior` may be a global defined somewhere else (this is a surprisingly common pattern in JavaScript land). This means that using an undefined variable such as `beforeSaveWarrior` is not considered an error by default.

To show undefined variables as errors and get quick fixes that import them, you need to [enable semantic checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking) in your Js file. The easiest way to to do this is to add `// @ts-check` at the top of your JavaScript file. Now undefined variables such as `beforeSaveWarrior` will be marked as errors. The lightbulb for the error should include a fix that adds the import